# How to remove Blank Spaces from the React app if there is no data available for it?

Tags: reactjs, api

Currently, I am working on a Dictionary App in React through an [API](https://dictionaryapi.dev/). In this API, some words have synonyms while some do not and the same is with antonyms and examples. I want to display them if they are, but if they aren't, I want to display "data not available". And also want to display them without any white spaces.
Can anyone help me?
This is the [live link](https://codesandbox.io/s/pocket-dictionary-yiwxf).
Here is the code for antonyms -

```
    import React from "react";

    const Antonyms = ({ mean }) => {
      return (
        <>
          {mean.map((Val) => {
            return Val.meanings.map((Means) => {
             return Means.definitions.map((Def) => {
               return (
                <>
                 <li className="text-capitalize fs-5 text-start">
                  {Def.antonyms}
                </li>
              </>
            );
          });
        });
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Antonyms;
```

Comment: it depends on the actual data, which you havn't shared yet . Does this return all the words including the ones which doesn't have any anonyms? because currently u are mapping several times. So it will be nice if you can share some sample data for each map or the initial data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional rendering as follows based on the existence of `Def.synonyms` value. If it's undefined or null, then component won't be shown.

Read more on conditional rendering [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

```
import React from "react";

const Synonyms = ({ mean }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {mean.map((Val) => {
        return Val.meanings.map((Means) => {
          return Means.definitions.map((Def) => {
            return (
              <>
                {Def.synonyms ? (
                  <li className="text-capitalize fs-5 text-start">
                    {`${Def.synonyms}`}
                  </li>
                )}
              </>
            );
          });
        });
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Synonyms;
```

Or you can return it as follows to show the "data not available" quote.

```
            return (
              <>
                <li className="text-capitalize fs-5 text-start">
                  {!Def.synonyms ? `${Def.synonyms}` : "data not available"}
                </li>
              </>
            );
```